# How to use scapy srp or sendp function

Tags: python, networking, scapy

I want to send a packet with scapy to another interface.
I have the wlan2 interface and i want my packet (that i generate) to be send there.

I've tried using send with iface but it has no effect.
I also tried using srp and just sendp but i am getting this strange result:

```
answer = srp(pkt[Ether]/ip/new_pkt/html1, iface="wlan2")
```

pkt[Ether] is a valid pkt that comes from the wlan2 interface and i can sniff it.
i am trying to generate an http response packet using its Ethernet layer.
But my response is always going to another interface and i think this is the problem.

[Wireshark Ethernet II](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCVvI.png)

The packets are grey...
The question is how to fix this? how do i send a legit packet to the wlan2 interface.